Does E[X] have finite mean if $tP(X>t)$ goes to zero?
I am wondering if we have the converse of the result in this post:
$tP(X>t)$ converges to zero if $X$ has a finite mean.
That is if X is a non-negative random variable, and $tP(X>t)$ goes to zero, do we then have that $E[X]<\infty$?
I tried to find a counterexample to show that it does not hold. For example $f(x)=1/x^2, x \ge 1$. But then $tP(X>t)=1$.

try something like $P(X > t) = C/(t \log t)$ (with $C$ a normalising constant)?

$P(X>t)$ specifies the complimentary cdf and in particular, can be any monotonic right continuous function which goes to $0$ as $t\to\infty$ and goes to $1$ as $t\to-\infty$.
So let $P(X\leq t)=1-\frac{1}{t\ln(t)}$ for $t\geq 2$ and $P(X\leq t)=0$ for all $t< 2$. This specifies the CDF. Check that $t\mapsto P(X\leq t)$ is right continuous, goes to $0$ at $t=-\infty$ and goes to $1$ at $t=\infty$.
Then $X$ is a positive random variable and
$$E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X>t)\,dt\geq \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t\ln(t)}\,dt=\infty$$
